# Amazon VPC: How to block inbound traffic on specific IP of an instance while allowing on other IPs of the same instance

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, firewall, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

### Specifications

I have an amazon VPC instance with the following specifications:

- Windows 2003 (32 bit).
- Two Network Interfaces each with 6 IPs.
- 6 instances of a software (called backweb) installed on the machine. Each for a different customer. (say customer1 to customer6).
- Each customer instance of backweb communicates on 2 IPs.

### Requirements

***Primarily my instance has 12 IPs and I want to block TCP 80 INBOUND TO 2 out of those 12 IPs. Remember all the 12 IPs are assigned to the same instance.***

- Block all http traffic on **customer1** instance of backweb, say IPs 10.0.10.1 and 10.0.10.2.
- Allow http traffic on **customer1** from a few specific IPs, say 2.96.219.283.
- Allow http traffic on all other customers (customer2 to customer6), say IPs 10.0.10.3 to 10.0.10.12.

### Possible solutions & Limitations

- (Not to mention) Amazon SGs and ACLs are not meant to control the traffic per my use case, as described above (see note at the end).
- Windows 2003 R2 firewall doesn't support such granular control to filter the inbound traffic to a specific IP on the local instance while letting other IPs (of the same instance) receive that.
- IPSec policies don't have an option to mention a specific IP of my windows instance to control traffic. It just gives an option "My IP Address", which actually means all the IP addresses on my machine.
- Adding another Network Interface to the instance; putting those IPs that need to block http on this additional NIC and controlling the traffic with SGs on that NIC. This is NOT POSSIBLE in our situation because it's a 32 bit machine and the largest possible instance type is either m1.medium or c1.medium. Either of them supports maximum 2 NICs, which the machine already has and we can't add a third one.

### Note why this can't be achieved with SGs and ACLs:

- **Security groups** are meant to control the traffic by **instance (or by ENI)**.
- **Network ACLs** are meant to control the traffic by **subnet**.

References:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html

P.S. Please read the details above thoroughly and ask me if the question is not clear. Don't just interpret it as a simple scenario looking at the heading.
And please stick to the problem, suggestions are appreciated but not  completely deviating from the issue.

Comment: "(Not to mention) Amazon SGs and ACLs are not meant to control the traffic on IP basis." <-- say what?!? Of course they are meant to limit access by IP.

Comment: @EEAA, could you try proving that with an evidence? My experience and apparently amazon's documentation too, doesn't tell they are meant to **limit access by IP**.

Comment: @EEAA, I've edited the question with reference to amazon doc on SG and ACLs.

Comment: just fyi, Your can represent a single IP as a "subnet" by using `/32` mask.

Comment: I believe I wasn't able to clarify the issue well. Just FYI, all this is our bread and butter and I know this is not achievable by SGs or ACLs unless hacked undocumented. 

@Mxx, I understand when you say "represent a single IP as a subnet by using /32 mask" too. This is not my requirement. You're talking about external IPs while I'm talking about the 12 IPs assigned to the same VPC instance. And I want just 2 out of those 12 IPs to STOP listening on TCP 80, while other 10 IPs (again on the same instance) KEEP listening on TCP 80.

Comment: @EEAA, I hope the above comment clarifies your confusion too. Let me know if it doesn't and I'll try to restate it.

Comment: If someone has downvoted the question considering the first comment. Then please reconsider; read the question and the AWS documentation and revert the downvote. The first comment by EEAA is not relevant to this scenario.

Comment: @Tariq - As mentioned below, you're running an unsupported app on an unsupported OS. That's where the downvotes are likely coming from. You may have to come to terms with the fact that there may be no solution that meets your requirements (which is my current line of thinking). People ask questions frequently here, and are given answers they don't want to hear, but are the correct answer. I honestly hope that's not the case here, but you probably ought to start considering it as a possibility.

Comment: EEAA. lol. Agree to your point that for tough nuts askers get the answers they don't want to hear. But seriously, giving wrong answers without catching the whole story or saying "you are doing it wrong" just because there isn't an easy way out of it, is not fair either. But I really appreciate your input and time. It definitely is a help out of courtesy. But I still hope someone comes up with different possibilities like netsh, IPSec policies etc. that I didn't think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone's curious about how I made through it OR runs into a similar situation. I had to choose one of the possible solutions I mentioned in the question.

> Adding another Network Interface to the instance; putting those IPs that need to block http on this additional NIC and controlling the traffic with SGs on that NIC.

I also mentioned the limitation with the above possible solution.

> This is NOT POSSIBLE in our situation because it's a 32 bit machine and the largest possible instance type is either m1.medium or c1.medium. Either of them supports maximum 2 NICs, which the machine already has and we can't add a third one.

Although the limitation is still there, this was the ONLY option I could testify to be working in my situation. So, I decided to move some of the customers to another machine and implement the above on both the machines. The detailed logical steps could be stated as:

1. Move 3 of 6 customer installations from the first windows instance to a clone of that windows instance. This will result in having 6 IPs on one windows instance.
2. Have 2 Network Interfaces with each windows instance. Say ENI-1 and ENI-2.
3. Those IPs that need to receive HTTP traffic, attach them to ENI-1.
4. Those IPs that need to block HTTP trafic, attach them to ENI-2.
5. Create two security groups; say http_sg_ALLOW and http_sg_BLOCK.
6. Add rules to http_sg_ALLOW, to allow HTTP traffic from whatever the sources you want to.
7. Apply http_sg_ALLOW to ENI-1.
8. Add rules to http_sg_BLOCK, to block HTTP traffic from whatever the sources you want to.
9. Apply http_sg_BLOCK to ENI-2.

Answer (score 0):

> Amazon SGs and ACLs are not meant to control the traffic on IP basis
>   (see note at the end).

This is categorically false.

Security Groups *can* be constructed using instance IDs, but you can also use CIDR subnets. This applies both to traffic that enters/exits your VPC **in addition to** also applying to traffic **within** your VPC. If you have a a "default" VPC configuration, there is a default SG that permits all traffic between SG members, but if you elect, you can remove that SG entirely and construct your own SG structure.

With regards to ACLs, as Mxx said above, they limit via subnet, including single-host `/32` subnets. Additionally, ACLs only apply to traffic that crosses a subnet boundary, so using them may not be applicable in your situation.

> Windows firewall is disabled by default. It's risky to enable it
>   because that can result in various unseen issues. Since this is a
>   production machine, so we don't want to take this risk. This would be
>   our last resort, though.

This is what a test/dev environment is for. Mock up your proposed rule set and test it, then deploy to your production machine.

> And I want just 2 out of those 12 IPs to STOP listening on TCP 80,
>   while other 10 IPs (again on the same instance) KEEP listening on TCP
>   80.

Well therein lies the rub. You're right that you cannot restrict access *to* a specific IP using a security group. You can only restrict access *to* a specific **host**. However, with some creative network ACLs, you might be able to come up with a configuration that works for you. But...

---

You're going about this in entirely the wrong way IMHO. Having 12 IP addresses on a server, for these purposes, is crazy. What you *should* be doing is having each instance of your software listening on a different port, and then put a routing layer in front of it. A small instance with nginx or the like would be more than sufficient, and that server can reverse proxy http traffic to the application. This would give you a single spot from which to perform your access control, which could be at the application layer in nginx *or* via security groups.

---

With regards to where to go from here - I don't envy your position. You're running an EOL, out-of support application on an (nearly) EOL, out-of-support operating system, deployed in an environment it was clearly not intended to be used in. I suspect this is why you're getting downvoted, though as mentioned below, I did not downvote you.

To be honest, if you are unable to upgrade to a recent OS or recent rev of the software (that supports binding to arbitrary ports), I would consider pulling out of EC2, and moving this application to a "legacy" hosting platform.

Comment: Apparently, you're not thinking out of the box.

Would you mind elaborating the part "to the IP Address(s) wanted" from your proposed answer. Tell exactly where you specify the TARGET IP of the instance (which is actually my question). Neither Security Groups nor ACLs have provision to specify this.

About "no type of firewall will prevent an application from listening on a port." I never asked to prevent an app from listening on a port, I asked to block the traffic to a specific IP on which the app is listening. We already have this in place with SonicWall in our data center.

Comment: If you still think I'm not getting it, please give some steps to specify the TARGET IP (both SG & ACL) in AWS console with an example.

Comment: @Tariq - example forthcoming. I should note, though, that you're being awfully abrasive for someone seeking help. You're getting free help here, I'd suggest toning down your demeanor a bit.

Comment: No hard feeling, but I got the same feel since your first comment. And then _"Honestly, I feel like you haven't even tried this"_ is not appreciating either. But your advice well taken. And waiting for the example.

Comment: @Tariq - no problem. Your question is much more clear now after your second edit. Originally, it was not clear that all of these IP addresses are on the same instance. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It is a 3rd party tool that we are using. They have stopped support of that version. And it's requirement is 2 IPs per installation instance. In a nutshell, the 12 IPs have a reason behind them. And there is a lot more involved in this than what I can explain for now. So, considering the architecture can't be changed. What options do I have?

Comment: If you downvoted my question for the reason you mentioned in your answer then please revert that. Like I said this architecture has a whole long story behind this. And to keep it simple I just mentioned the part related to the problem. However you can think of editing your statements about SG and ACLs to be concise with the question.

Comment: @Tariq - Don't make assumptions about downvotes. It was not me.

Comment: Thanks. It was an assumption that's why I used IF. About usage of legacy tools, OS, I agree and upgrade is already in plan but right now we are in transition from legacy datacenter to AWS. Our product is a huge CDN and it is a huge effort to upgrade these elements. And anyone can be in a situation that I am in right now, for various unpredictable, unforeseen reasons. This never means we stop finding solutions to such problems.

Comment: @EEAA aside, Windows Server 2003 isn't EOL, out of support, it's in extended support for another year and a half ( http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=Windows+Server+2003&Filter=FilterNO )

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler fair point.